# Kafka- Best practices in case of slow consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a use case in which I have 3 Kafka consumers writing to a single topic and messages in each consumer is needed to be processed in order. In case, If there is lag in one of the consumer, a message which is needed to be processed earlier is going to get dropped(wrote condition). So, is there a way by which I can maintain the order of these messages.

Answer (score 1):

Messages are always ordered in a Kafka partition. Typically, all messages belonging to a certain key land in a certain partition (by partitioning logic).

> I have a use case in which I have 3 Kafka consumers writing to a single topic

I suppose, you mean you have 3 consumers *reading* from a single topic

There are 2 cases here:

1. Each consumer gets all messages in the topic.
2. Each consumer gets only a portion of messages (partitions) in the topic.

**In case #1**

You can have 3 consumers each with a different `group.id` so that each will consume all sets of messages.
Here, the slower consumer will not slow down other consumers. Because each consumer runs typically, in its own thread or process.

**In case #2**

You can have 3 consumers with the same `group.id` so that each consumer will get its own share of partitions.
A message consumed by one consumer will not be consumed by another.
Here also, the slower consumer will not slow down other consumers. Because each consumer will consume only its own set of partitions.

> In case, If there is lag in one of the consumer, a message which is
>   needed to be processed earlier is going to get dropped(wrote
>   condition)

There is no implicit dropping in Kafka, you have to just drop the message yourself after polling it.

To check lag, I think, you can start off with `consumer.endOffsets()` and `consumer.position()`, the difference should give you the lag. Depending on the lag, you may choose to drop your messages.

```
consumer.assignment().forEach( topicPartition -> {
      long currentPos = consumer.position(topicPartition);
      long endOfPartition = consumer.endOffsets(Collections.singletonList(topicPartition)).get(topicPartition);
});
```